# libcurl error 79 (Error in SSH Layer) when listing SFTP directory

Tags: c++, sftp, libcurl, libssh2

I'm trying to get the listing of a directory with libcurl in C++ from a SFTP server, but I get a Error 79 - Error in the SSH layer.

There are around 8000 files to list and I get the error sometimes after 5min, sometimes after 10min. It works correctly on directories that contains only a few files (<300).

```
size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void* buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* memory) 
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)memory;
    mem->memory = (char*)realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);

    if(mem->memory == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), buffer, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

    return realsize;
}

...

struct MemoryStruct chunk;
chunk.memory = (char*)malloc(1);
chunk.size = 0;

curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_URL, "sftp://username@hostname/dir");
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 22);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES, CURLSSH_AUTH_PUBLICKEY);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE, path);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE, path);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)&chunk);
m_errorCode = curl_easy_perform(m_curl);
```

I'm using libcurl v4.3.0 and libssh2 v1.4.3. I have the same problem with the command line tool. But don't get more info in verbose mode.

Any ideas ? 
Thanks

Comment: @bgbarcus, unfortunately not. My workaround so far is to list all files starting with character 'a', then 'b', etc.

Comment: @Marc: From my experience, it wasn't possible to list files matching a specific prefix via SFTP using libcurl. Could you explain how you could list files starting with 'a', 'b', etc?

Comment: Too many problems with libcurl and libssh2, I have now switched to libssh.